# not understanding boolean output when comparing true and false statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-expression

for the below code, I am not understanding how this is working. I am trying to learn the basics online and no matter what I cannot break the below. but if the flag value is originally false, then essentially line four is saying false = false or false....which is TRUE

```
def any_lowercase4(s):

    flag = False
    for c in s:
        flag = flag or c.islower()
    return flag

print(any_lowercase4('TT'))
```

It will then print `False`

Comment: 'TT' doesn't have any lowercase letters, so isn't `False` the right answer? About your specific question: `False or False` should be `False` logically. e.g. "up is down or in is out" compares two false statements and the correct outcome is false.

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed by your summary of the Boolean logic. `False or False` is `False`, not `True`. Are you confusing the `=` for an equality comparison? That's written `==` in Python, a single `=` does an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `False or False` is False (not True as you propose)

You can see this with this simple example:

```py
>>> x = False
>>> y = False
>>> print (x or y)
False
>>> z = True
>>> print (x or z)
True
>>>
```

The complete truth table for `or` is:

```
F or F = F
T or F = T
F or T = T
T or T = T
```

where T = True and F = False

Comment: thanks! i used my logic using string 'false' and it came out true. I see that now the boolean False in the function will return false.

Answer (score 0):

print(any_lowercase4('TT'))
essentially says please check if any character is lower, 
which is not. 
So, either check for Tt, which outputs True.
In Python, islower() is a built-in method used for string handling.
The islower() methods returns “True” if all characters in the string are lowercase, Otherwise, It returns “False”.

```
b='Tt' 
c='tt' 
print (b. islower())
print (c. islower())

for i in b:
    print (b. islower())
```

Outputs
False
True
False
False